# como usar SessionHandlerInterface y mysq

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

hola amigos soy nuevo aquí tengo una clase con la que deseo manejar las sesiones php y subirlas al servidor tengo esta clase

```
class Session implements \SessionHandlerInterface{
private $db;
private $id;
private $last_time;

public function close (){//Cierra la sesión actual
    $this->db = null;
    return true;
}
public function create_sid (){//Devuelve un nuevo ID de sesión
    $sessionId = parent::create_sid();
    return $sessionId;
}
public function destroy ( $session_id ){//Destruir una sesión
    $d = $this->db->delete('z_sessions',[
                'sessions_id[=]'=>'session_id'
            ]);
    $this->db->exesent(['session_id'=>$session_id]);
    return ($this->db->affectedRows > 0)?true:false;
}
public function gc ( $maxlifetime ){//Eliminar las sesiones antiguas
    $c = time() - $maxlifetime;
    $this->db->delete('z_sessions',[
            'last_activity[<]'=>'maxlife'
        ]);
    $this->db->exesent(['maxlife'=>$c]);
    return ($this->db->affectedRows > 0)?true:false;
}
public function open ( $save_path , $session_name ){//Inicializar una sesión
    $this->db = new db();
    return true;
}
public function read ( $session_id ){
    $ss = $this->db->select('*','z_sessions',['sessions_id[=]'=>$session_id]);
    if($ss){
        $r = $this->db->get_result();
        if(!empty($r)){
            return $r->sdata;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
public function write ( $session_id , $session_data ){
    $this->last_time = time();
    $fecha = insertFecha();
    $this->db->replace('z_sessions',[
        'sessions_id'=>'sessions_id',
        'ip_address'=>'ip_address',
        'user_agent'=>'user_agent',
        'sdata'=>'sdata',
        'last_activity'=>'last_activity',
        'fechas_id'=>'fechas_id'
    ]);
    $this->db->exesent([
        'sessions_id'=>$session_id,
        'ip_address'=>iPclient()."'",
        'user_agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        'sdata'=>$session_data,
        'last_activity'=>$this->last_time,
        'fechas_id'=>$fecha
    ]);
    return true;
}   }
```

luego llamo:

```
$sh = new Session;
session_set_save_handler($sh, true);
```

Mi base de datos es:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS z_sessions (
sessions_id varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
user_agent text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 sdata text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 last_activity int(11) NOT NULL,
 fechas_id bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY z_sessions_id_unique (sessions_id),
KEY z_sessions_fechas_id_foreign (fechas_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

si $_SESSION['algo'] = 1 ella funciona pero si recargo la pagina y ejecuto algo como

```
if($_SESSION['algo'] == 1){ echo "hay Algo"; }
else{ echo "No hay nada"; }
```

siempre me va a decir No hay nada;

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Antes de realizar esto `if($_SESSION['algo'] == 1){ echo "hay Algo"; }
else{ echo "No hay nada"; }` inicias la sesión? `session_start()`?

Comment: mi archivo index por donde trabajo todo esta asi.

Comment: require_once(CTL."Session.php");
@session_start(); if($_SESSION['algo'] == 1){ echo "hay Algo"; } else{ echo "No hay nada"; }